# Why does Spring Boot backend JAR file run only for a short while on Ubuntu? How to make it run as a service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ubuntu, jar

I wrote a Spring Boot RESTful API backend, compiled it to `backend.jar` file and ran it on Ubuntu (EC2 of AWS) by command `java -jar backend.jar` . It can serve requests well, but it seems that it runs only for a short while and then disappears, so the following requests fail to be served. I can rerun `java -jar backend.jar` but it works only for a short while.

How to make the `backend.jar` permanent like a service?
(I am new to server administration)

Comment: Have you checked the logs, why it ends itself? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Create a user for your service

```
$ sudo useradd thangtran
$ sudo passwd thangtran
$ sudo chown thangtran:thangtran backend.jar
$ sudo chmod 500 backend.jar
```

Solution 1: Use systemd (recommended). In directory `/etc/systemd/system` , create file `backend.service` has content

```
[Unit]
Description=A Spring Boot application
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=thangtran
ExecStart=/path/to/backend.jar SuccessExitStatus=143 

[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

See more at https://viblo.asia/p/su-dung-systemd-de-chinh-sua-service-linux-m68Z0PJNZkG

Solution 2: System V init

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/backend.jar /etc/init.d/your-app
$ sudo service your-app start
```

Log at `/var/log/backend.log`
Application's process id tracked at `/var/run/backend/backend.pid`